# it is showing object cannot cast to DBNull

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, ado.net

```
SqlCommand sd1 = new SqlCommand("select sum(pric) from cart where uid='" + 
                 Convert.ToInt32( Session["uid"]) + "'",con);
// sd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
int var1 = Convert.ToInt32( sd1.ExecuteScalar());
```

Comment: Seems there is no row for the `Session["uid"]`.

Comment: why are you converting and thus concatenating a string with an int...why not try ..."select sum(pric) from cart where uid='" + 
                 Session["uid"].ToString() + "'", ...

Answer (score 0):

- If there is no record then `DBNull.Value` is returned instead. You need to account for this in your casting. The following will cast to a nullable `int` so you have a representation if no records were found.
- Also use parameters for your queries, not string concatenation.

Code:

```
int? intResult;
using(SqlCommand sd1 = new SqlCommand("select sum(pric) from cart where uid=@uid", con))
{
    sd1.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@uid", SqlDbType.Int){Value = Convert.ToInt32(Session["uid"])});
    var result = sd1.ExecuteScalar();
    intResult = Syste.DBNull.Value == result
      ? (int?) null
      : (int?) result;
}
```